# MySQL (Percona): Multiple simultaneous long-running connections

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm running a distributed app in the cloud where clients keep open multiple long-running connections to a MySQL (Percona) server.

After updating to the latest Percona release, the maximum number of simultaneously connected clients has dropped significantly. In the past, with the previous Percona version, it was used successfully with up to 8K connections, now it struggles to get above 3K.

By "struggles" I mean that when the connection bottleneck has been reached, connecting to MySQL times out even in the command line. When I do manage to connect, `show processlist` doesn't show any hanging queries or locks. So the connections that are established work just fine. The Apache webserver serving the PHP webapp used to monitor the project also hangs indefinitely.

Here's the `my.cnf` I use, patched together from various guides.

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit               = 16384
table_open_cache               = 16384
character_set_server           = utf8mb4
max_connections                = 16384
expire_logs_days               = 10
max_binlog_size                = 100M
innodb_open_files              = 16384
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_read_io_threads         = 4
innodb_write_io_threads        = 4
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 0
innodb_log_file_size           = 128M
innodb_open_files              = 4000
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 1
thread_pool_size               = 16
local_infile                   = 1
skip-name-resolve
thread_cache_size              = 16384
thread_handling                = pool-of-threads
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 64M
```

And the Percona version I'm running:

```
mysqld --version
Ver 8.0.15-6 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release '6', Revision '63abd08')
```

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`

Hardware:

- CPU: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8175M CPU @ 2.50GHz`
- RAM: `32G`

The queries I'm running are all based on unique indexes (no joins), tables are all InnoDB. The same configuration worked fine until the update to Percona 8.

The `my.cnf` settings I had to remove after the upgrade as they were no longer supported are:

- `innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 0`
- `query_cache_size               = 0`
- `query_cache_type               = 0`

Things I tried:

- I ran `mysqltuner.pl` but didn't get any relevant advice from it.
- `ulimit -n` and `ulimit -s` show values significantly higher than what I'm using (`1048576` and `16384` specifically).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: This question is more suited for [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as this question seams to be about configuration purely

Comment: Moderator, please REMOVE, this is on dba.stackexchange.com as question 240712.  Thanks